# Access parts of 'sub-type' of union type

Tags: typescript

If I have a union type such as:

```js
type StateUpdate = { key: 'surname', value: string }
| { key : 'age', value: number };
```

This is handy as it allows me to determine the type of the value from the key.

However, I'd like to be able to have other functions which can only be called with a valid 'key' from the union type. In the above example, that'd mean it'd have to be either 'surname' or 'age'.

I know I can determine another type as:

```js
type ValidKey = 'surname' | 'age';
```

Then I may have some arbitrary function such as:

```js
(keyName: ValidKey) => (console.log(keyName)); // ...or whatever
```

This requires that I always ensure the two correspond. Is there a good way to handle this automatically, or perhaps there's a better way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [indexed type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
type ValidKey = StateUpdate ['key'];
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIFUwBNHQLxQN5QGsIQAuKAcgGcBXAJwDt4BbCcgGigDd4AbaiMpWC0AlvQDmUAL4AoKPKgAfPIWJly8caw7c+AqPWpMARhFrSA3DNCQoANV4i0AaWJQccTKgxIoAbXIiEHIAXQsgA)

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for this; forever impressed with the type system in typescript!